# How to remove a channel (text or voice) from a category channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am creating a discord bot using Discord.js. I can set the parent/category of the text and voice channels fine and switch them to other category channels as I please. However, I cannot make the channel be parentless once it has already had one.
To be more specific, If I dynamically create a text channel it will be automatically placed towards the top without being included in a category.

[image: Test channel is the channel that was created]

When I choose to include it inside a category it goes inside just like it should.
But there is no way for me to remove the channel out of the category and place it back at the top again without deleting the channel and recreating it. To reiterate, I can move it into the category fine, but I cannot move it back up where the general and tok channels are.

[image: Test channel inside test category]

I looked at the channel object in the console and the only thing that was different was the parentID. Since obviously 'general' does not have a parent, the ID is null. The parentID is not a read-only property, so I figured I could just change the parentID of 'test-channel' to null to fix the problem, but that did not work either. As far as I can see, there is not a way to revert it back to being parentless once it has been adopted.

I am using the standard way (according to the docs) of assigning it a parent ([link to the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=setParent)). However, instead of an ID I am using the actual channel object.

I know this possible by just dragging and dropping the channel out of the category and back up top. So that makes me think there has to be a way to do this using this API.

Comment: Did you try channel.setParent(null) ?

Comment: I am really surprised I did not think of that. Wow. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setParent(null)` definitely should work. I tested it recently and it worked like a charm. I use Discord.js 11.4.2.